# PDF Compression - HTML to PDF (wkhtmltopdf)

Tags: java, pdf, merge, compression, wkhtmltopdf

### Background

I'm working on a Scala/Java project where we convert individual **HTML files to PDF files.** We then merge the individual files into one larger complete PDF file.

For the converting we are using [**sPDF**](https://github.com/cloudify/sPDF) which is built on top of **[wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)**. For the merging we use [**PDFMergerUtility**](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFMergerUtility.html).

*The reasons for making individual files is a bit complicated - but it should be noted we can't make one big PDF off the bat and have to make the individual files first.*

### The issue

Initially we had no problems with this approach - however as the system has grown - so have the final PDF files. We went from files that were **2MB-3MB** to files that are **20MB**. I would like to know if there is any obvious compression methods or techniques we could use?

**There is a lot of shared content across the individual files** but since we're just merging them as isolated/independent files (as in, none of the content that is the same across the individual files is being reused to save space) it doesn't make a difference in bringing down the file size.

If I manually ZIP the final PDF file it greatly reduces the file size -as obviously there is a lot of repeated content.

So one option might just be to zip the PDF after I've finished the merging, but I would prefer to compress it during the merger process or conversion process.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried --lowquality option for wkhtmltopdf it reduce the size of the generated file for me it reduce it from 8MB to a mere 200kb

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Sejda](https://www.sejda.org/) to merge, it's Java, open source and based on a fork of PDFBox. It can generate PDF files using object streams (PDFBox currently doesn't support that) and, in case it doesn't reduce the size that much, you can try to pipe its 'compress' task which goes through the document removing unused resources and compressing images.

It's battle tested as engine behind [PDFsam](https://www.pdfsam.org/) so, if you want to give it a quick test and see what's the outcome, just download PDFsam, use the merge module with your files (and compression flag on) and the result is what Sejda will generate.